# Apache Preset is Disabled

Tags: apache2

When I check the status of Apache, I see this:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
```

The preset is disabled. How can I enable preset?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Apache on a modern release of Ubuntu, then you can use `systemctl` to enable the web server, ensuring it starts after every reboot:

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

`vendor preset: disabled` means that the default upon installation is to keep it disabled. There's no need to change the vendor preset.
After running this:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

If you see that  "apache2.service; disabled; Vendor preset: disabled" then run for enabling apache2.service.

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

If your `apache2` is not running then run the command.
sudo service apache2 restart
then check with

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```